# How can I order entries in a Dask dataframe for display in seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, dask

I'm trying to get a Seaborn barplot containing the top *n* entries from a dataframe, sorted by one of the columns.

In Pandas, I'd typically do this using something like this:

```
df = df.sort_values('ColumnFoo', ascending=False)
sns.barplot(data=df[:10], x='ColumnFoo', y='ColumnBar')
```

Trying out Dask, though, there is (fairly obviously) no option to sort a dataframe, since dataframes are largely deferred objects, and sorting them would eliminate many of the benefits of using Dask in the first place.

Is there a either get ordered entries from a dataframe, or to have Seaborn pick the top *n* values from a dataframe's column?

Comment: Have you seen http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.nlargest ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're moving data to seaborn then it almost certainly fits in memory.  I recommend just converting to a Pandas dataframe and then doing the sorting there.

Generally, once you've hit the small-data regime there is no reason to use Dask over Pandas.  Pandas is more mature and a smoother experience.  Dask Dataframe developers recommend using Pandas when feasible.